# Existence and Unicity Weak, Strong, Pathwise, In Law, etc... for SDE's

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I feel always confused with weak, strong, pathwise unicity and or existence for Stochastic Differential Equations. It is mainly my own fault and I should do something about it.

But it would be much easier if anyone has a one pager document that sums up this matter. I mean by that first a reminder of all definition of concepts, second the implications from one definiton to another or condition that makes th concepts equivalents.

Best regards

Comment: You might find Section 5.1 (page 74) of [these notes](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~beresty/teach/StoCal/sc3.pdf) useful.

Comment: @ Ben Derrett : Thx, I'll read these notes carefully.

Comment: @ Sasha: argh fooled by my french "unicité", uniqueness would have been a more suitable word though. Best regards

Comment: @ Ben Derret : About remark 5.2, I quite disagree with the conclusion, it is not the fact that the tossed solution is not adapted that cause the problem, we could toss in both solution in an adapted way with respect to the natural filtration of the fixed brownian motion, but there is no way to do that together with keeping indistinguishabilty of this third solution with any of both first solutions. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge: Perhaps you could ask a separate question about that remark?

Comment: @ Ben derrett : Well I think I got it now but I still beleive that the argument is not complete. What it said is that if all solutions are strong then there is only one solution (i.e. one functional of the path of the bm), otherwise we can build another one which is weak (N.B. it is an affirmation and not demonstration in the remark but I think it is true). Pathwise uniqueness has still to be proved rigourously, this is why the argument is not complete in my opinion. Best regards

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35961027/uniqueness.pdf) could be of some help. Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for though.